# ОпошлИть или опОшлить?

Tags: фонетика

По идее, "пОшлый", значит — опОшлить. Но чаще можно услышать "опошлИть". А как все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно [опОшлить](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EE%EF%EE%F8%EB%E8%F2%FC). Неправильное "опошлИть" связано с тенденцией языка к переносу ударения на конец слова, но нормативным вариант с ударением на"и" на данный момент не является.